# The current path of a process

Tags: process, cwd

Suppose I write a program, which outputs a file under a relative path (as opposed to a full/absolute path) - let's say, the current path.

Then I compile it and store the executable under some dir `path1`.

1. Now I run the executable, while I am under a different dir `path2`. The
   executable will  output a file under `path2` instead of `path1`.

   I wonder why the executable doesn't  write a file under `path1` instead? In other words, why is the "current path" `path2` not `path1`?
2. If during run-time, the executable opens a file stored in `path3`, why does the current path become `path3`, although I run the executable from `path2` and the executable was stored in `path1`?

How does the OS assign and change the current path for a process, during it's run-time?

Comment: I'm not really sure what do you mean by current path. Take a look at [chdir(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir), perhaps it's what you look for.

Comment: Can you give the code you have try?

Comment: The initial directory a program runs in its father's current directory. For example, if you launch a program from a shell, the shell's current directory will be the initial directory of the program. Does that answer (partially) your question or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @lgeorget:thanks, that answer the first question. The second question, for example, when you run an emacs process, and open in emacs a file in `path3`, why is the current dir changes to `path3`?

Comment: Actually, it might not be changed. A process can create or open a file inother place than its current directory. I'll post a proper answer.

Comment: @lgeorget: but that is what happens in emacs, evince, and all applications I have seen.

Comment: @Tim That's a fairly common mechanism, you really often need to open file outside of your current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1** : Why is the directory where a program is installed not the initial directory of the process when running the program?

Actually, the installation path of a program is irrelevant. What matters is the current path of the *father* process. In case of a program launched from a shell, the father process is the shell itself so the initial current directory of the new process is the shell's current directory.

**Question 2** : How can a process create a file outside from its current directory?

There are two ways to give the path of a file: absolute path and relative path. An absolute path is interpreted from the root of the filesystem (`/`) and start with a slash ("/"). A relative path is interpreted from the current directory of the process. So if you have two directories, for example `/path2` and `/path2/path3`, and a process whose current directory is `path2`, it can open a file `path3/file`. This path is relative (it doesn't start with a slash) so it's computed from the current directory `path2`. And finally, the new file's complete path is `/path2/path3/file`. So a process running in a given directory may create file outside of it.

**Question 3** : How does the OS assign and change the current path for a process, during its running?

A process can ask the OS for changing its current directory by the mean of the `chdir(2)` system call (provided that it has needed permissions on the new directory for it, etc. etc.). That's a different mechanism which has nothing to do with opening files. Opening files is done through another system call (namely `open(2)`).

Comment: thanks. for Q2, I am not asking about *creating a new file*. I ask about *opening an existing file*, and then the current path of the process changes to the path for the file.

Comment: Creating and opening are actually quite the same. Creating is opening a new file. About changing the current directory, that's another operation done by the process. By no mean, you can change your current directory by opening a file.